# R Separate by location?

Tags: r

I have a column(char) in a data frame.  The column consists of data that is formatted this way:

```
df <- c("Apr 19 DBH", "Apr 19 PPA", "Apr 19 MI", "Apr 19 Total")
```

I want to separate the Apr 19 from the following characters, creating 2 columns:

```
Date       Prod
-----------------
Apr 19     DBH
Apr 19     PPA
Apr 19     MI
Apr 19     Total
```

I can `substr(df, 1, 7)` into a column, but then still need to separate out the characters after position 7.

I thought `separate` would be a good solution, but the `sep =` looks to require a string of some type. I only have spaces, and in this case, I have 2 spaces. I could probably paste a character into the string and the separate on that, but feels clumsy. Can you separate by only a first character position? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `extract` :

```
tidyr::extract(df, col, into = c('Date', 'Prod'), regex = "(.*)\\s+(\\w+)")

#    Date  Prod
#1 Apr 19   DBH
#2 Apr 19   PPA
#3 Apr 19    MI
#4 Apr 19 Total
```

This divides the data into two parts, 1st it captures everything until last whitespace and 2nd the last word in the column.

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(col = df)
```

Comment: This worked.  Have to get familar with the string after regex... my self-teaching reference materials do not list anything like this...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `str_split` function from the `stringr` package.

Note that the regular expression `" {2,}"` instructs the function to split on 2 or more spaces.

```
library(stringr)
str_split(df, pattern = " {2,}", simplify = TRUE)
     [,1]     [,2]    
[1,] "Date"   "Prod"  
[2,] "Apr 19" "DBH"   
[3,] "Apr 19" "PPA"   
[4,] "Apr 19" "MI"    
[5,] "Apr 19" "Total"
```

Data

```
df <- c("Date       Prod", "Apr 19     DBH", "Apr 19     PPA", "Apr 19     MI", 
"Apr 19     Total ")
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) read.table** Insert a semicolon after the last space and read it in using semicolon as the field separator.  No packages are used.

```
s <- sub("(.* )", "\\1;", df)
read.table(text = s, sep = ";", as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

IF we knew that there is no more than one space in the first field and at least two separating it from the second field then the first line could be simplified to:

```
s <- sub("  ", ";", df)
```

**2) read.fwf** Another base R solution is to use `read.fwf` to read fixed width fields.

```
n <- max(nchar(df))
read.fwf(textConnection(df), c(7, n-7), strip.white = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```